# Remove Environment.Newline from TextBlock but not from DataSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, newline, carriage-return

I am creating a WPF screen (using MVVM pattern) which displays log entries in a `ListView` in `TextBlock`, including exception details.

```
<GridViewColumn
    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.Width="1*"
    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.MinWidth="123"
    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsHidden="{Binding ExceptionDataIsHidden}"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ExceptionData, Mode=OneWay}"
    Header="Exception Data"/>
```

Due to the way data is logged, exception strings include numerous carriage returns / line breaks. Example:

> ```
> System.BigBadException: Stuff blew up -> Some file location 
>   at SomeMethodCallAtTheTopLevel: line 1234
>   at SomeMethodCallAtTheNextLevel: line 123
>   at SomeMethodCallAtAnotherLevel: line 12
>   at SomeMethodCallOnBottomLevel: line 1
> ```

Some exceptions can be quite large.  This becomes a problem when displaying entries as rows in my `ListView`.  Instead of nicely displaying each entry on one line, the `Environment.Newline` characters force each row to be multiline, thereby causing the user a lot more scrolling when looking through row entries.

I realize one simple solution is to remove the line breaks manually as such:

```
foreach (LogEntry entry in allEntries)
{
  entry.ExceptionData = entry.ExceptionData.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""); 
}
```

**Problem**

I want the text to display in the `GridViewColumn` cells as if all `Newline` have been removed.  However, I want to preserve these line breaks in the data.  The user has the ability to right-click a cell and copy it's value to the clipboard.  When pasting into a file (say Notepad), I want the line breaks present to make the formatting easier to read.

Is there a way to ignore line breaks in xaml or by other means?  *Or do I want to eat my cake and have it too?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution for now is along the lines of the discussion with K_Ram.  However, I didn't want to add another property to my `ViewModel`.  Also, I wanted a general solution that could work for future projects as well.  Therefore I went with creating a simplified converter class.

```
public class RemoveNewLineConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var val = value as string ?? string.Empty;
    return val.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Method not implemented");
  }
}
```

Then, usage in xaml is simply:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyWpfHelpers.Converters;assembly=MyWpfHelpers"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Converters:RemoveNewLineConverter x:Key="NoNewline"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<GridViewColumn
    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.Width="1*"
    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.MinWidth="123"
    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsHidden="{Binding ExceptionDataIsHidden}"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ExceptionData, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource NoNewline}}"
    Header="Exception Data"/>
```

Comment: Nicely done. That is much more elegant than putting in a second property. Although, may I recommend a slight bit of code refactoring? You can do "var val =  value as string ?? string.Empty;". Then you don't have to cast it below; it will already be a string.

Comment: @K_Ram Thanks for the suggestion.  I've never used that operator, so that was a nice gem to learn.  I've edited in your suggestion for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can create a hidden field that holds the raw data and use a field for display. Or use an entirely different display model. Preserve your raw data somewhere.

Intercept the right-click/copy event--make your own, perhaps, if you haven't already--and substitute the desired raw data.

Comment: I have considered this.  I do already handle the right-click option myself.  The problem with this approach is that there can be thousands of log entries.  I'd rather not have to duplicate this field if possible, though it's an option if all else fails.

Comment: Good point. It can be pretty memory intensive. But the raw data has to be somewhere. I guess what you're looking for is a way for the List View to just ignore new lines. I'm not sure there is such a thing.  I'm also wondering how readable these logs will be as it is, just as one big line. Perhaps it'd make more sense to display the exception data of the active row to the side in your form and keep the line breaks? The lines could just have the shorter message, or a small portion of the exception data.

Comment: Clarification, in absence of editing capabilities: "The ListView rows could just have the shorter message, or a small portion of the exception data."